# Using Like in a Sub Query

Tags: subquery

Using Like in a Sub Query

**Table A**

```
Part    Description
--------------------
Part1   Top Cover
Part2   Botom Cover
Part3   xxxx
Part4   Cover
Part5   yyyy
```

**Table B**

```
Keyword
-----------
Cover
```

Result should be

```
Part    Description
--------------------
Part1   Top Cover
Part2   Botom Cover
Part4   Cover
```

I want to know the part in table a which has description as COVER

I used the following query

```
SELECT Part FROM TableA WHERE Description LIKE '%' + (SELECT Keyword FROM TableB    ) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want to match all keywords from tableB. Cross-join is good choice here. Instead of sub query use join

```
select part 
from tableA,
tableB
where Description LIKE '%Keyword%'
```